# Highest weights of irreducible components of tensor product of irreducible sl(3)-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I am study the representation theory of $sl(3)$ and I have a question about the tensor representation of irreducible $sl(3)$-modules as follows:

For each weight $\mu$, let $L(\mu)$ be the irreducible $sl(3)$-module of highest weight $\mu$ and assume that $L(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta)$ are finite dimensional.

Is it true that the tensor representation $L(\alpha) \otimes L(\beta) =\bigoplus_{i=1}^n L(\lambda_i) $ satisfying that for each $\lambda_i$ $\lambda_i = \alpha + \gamma$ for some weight $\gamma$ of the module $L(\beta)$?

I have computed several cases, this result hold in those cases.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Yes, this is true. It follows from Weyl character formula, I think. There is a general result to this effect in Humphreys' book, but my copy is in my office.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you mean the book <<Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory>> ?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: I found this exercise. Thank you !  :)

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152837/highest-weights-of-irreducible-components-of-tensor-product-of-irreducible-sl3?noredirect=1.